# Simplifying Chain of Conditional Variances given a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$Suppose $X,Y,W$ form a Markov chain $X \to Y \to W$.
Can we simplify the following expression?
\begin{align*}
E [ \Var ( \Var (X\mid Y) \mid W)]
\end{align*}
Because we have a Markov chain, that is $p(x\mid y)=p(x\mid y,w)$, we have that
\begin{align*}
E[X\mid Y]&=E[X\mid Y,W]\\
\Var(X\mid Y)&=\Var(X\mid Y,W)\\
\end{align*}

If we were to replace $\Var$ with expected value we can use towering property of expected value that is
\begin{align*}
E \left[ E \left(E [X\mid Y] \mid W\right)\right]&=E \left[ E \left(E [X\mid Y,W] \mid W\right)\right]\\
&=E[E[X\mid W]]=E[X]
\end{align*}

Can we do something similar for $E \left[ \Var \left( \Var (X\mid Y) \mid W\right)\right]$?

One thing we can show is 
\begin{align*}
E \left[ \Var \left( \Var (X\mid Y) \mid W\right)\right]=E \left[ \Var \left( \Var (X\mid Y,W) \mid W\right)\right]
\end{align*}
but I am not sure if this helps at all.

Would be grateful for any ideas. Thank you very much

Comment: Try to write the variance as an expectation, i.e., use $\mathrm{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. Maybe this helps...

Comment: The inside or the outside. I tried it get messy.

Comment: I would start with the inner one and then try to apply the towering property. After that, the outer one may be less messy...